Looking for some advice regarding research collaboration
I am currently in the middle of my one-year MSc. thesis at a non-brand University in Europe. Our University requires an external examiner to be part of the project. My thesis surrounds a proven unsolvable problem that was written up decades ago. As a long shot, we reached out to one of the professors who defined this problem long ago.
After many exchanged emails, they read the research proposal and stated that they are working on a similar problem and would like to do a research collaboration between the advisor, them, and me, and also invited me to visit them at their University (which is a T10 overall, T30/T20 in my field) to collaborate this summer. I'm heading there in the next coming weeks and staying for a few days.
The questions
First and foremost, this thing doesn't really feel like it should happen at the current point and time in my education and academic career. Does this happen? When does this happen? It feels surreal, and I feel like maybe I am getting hyped about something that is too good to be true.
What sort of expectations should I have about this? Is this a way to "sneak" into a PhD programme in the US if it goes well? How should I best prepare for the visit and collaboration to maximize this opportunity?

While a collaboration might be inconsistent with the role of an external examiner, I don't see the same problems that you seem to. The advisor and, obviously, the external person likely know the wider field better than you do and are in a better place to judge. It sounds like a dream opportunity, assuming everyone is ethical.
Visiting a more prestigious university is also a positive thing. I don't understand your hesitation.
You need to look at the requirements for doctoral study in the US. This opportunity seems like a good, though probably unnecessary, one.
I don't see any red flags, given what you write here.
However, see the requirements for admission to doctoral programs in the US (and elsewhere) here: How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in Country X?


First and foremost, this thing doesn't really feel like it should happen at the current point and time in my education and academic career. Does this happen? When does this happen?

To me, this actually seems fairly normal. A "good" Master's student who does solid academic work also benefits the PI, especially if they are able to be independent and contribute to the direction of the project. In turn, supervisors will often try to reward Master's students (who usually don't get paid) by supporting their academic journey- helping them make connections, funding them to present at a conference, etc. . What you've written isn't necessarily the norm for all Master's students, but seems reasonable and common for high-achieving ones.
I'd also like to note that you probably shouldn't take as much stock in overall field-based university rankings once you get into a specific subfield. For example, a university that has a middling ranking overall might be known in the subfield for having a very strong group in a specific niche, or vice versa.
Asking your potential collaborator to be an examiner might be a bit of a loophole to be able to fund their visit to your university. I'm mostly aware of this trick being used for doctoral defences (albeit with stricter ethical guidelines). So long as they didn't contribute to the part of the work that they're evaluating, it should be in the ethical clear.

What sort of expectations should I have about this?

At least in my field, the expectation would be to have some very intense days of discussion when you visit (as well as some nice dinners and impromptu sightseeing), followed by a lot of hard work when you get back home. There will presumably be a very optimistic timeline to write a joint publication- which will help you with grad school applications, but don't forget to also finish your MSc thesis.

Is this a way to "sneak" into a PhD programme in the US if it goes well? (I have no idea how that actual process works).

See the canonical question/Buffy's answer. You should also talk to your PI about this: they know you and your field, so they can give you more tailored advice.

How should I best prepare for the visit and collaboration to maximize this opportunity?

Read up on the work of the person/group you're visiting- you don't need to know everything, but have some idea of what they do. Ask your PI if they want you to prepare anything specific (e.g. slides). If they don't, try to prepare some version of your notes/work so far that's easily digestible and shareable, and be prepared to explain what you've worked on so far in a clear and concise way.
Other than that, pack defensively (bring comfortable shoes/clothes, weather protection against rain/sun/heat, basic medication for allergies/flu/headaches - assume you'll be busy all day) and try to start out well-rested. Take plenty of notes when you're there, don't assume you'll be able to remember everything. And don't forget to enjoy yourself a bit- science isn't serious all the time, remembering that your impressively-ranked collaborators are people too and trying to connect with them on that level can help the atmosphere tremendously.
